# Cross-product in law of total probability

Tags: probability

I'm working with the quantity $P(E_1)P(E_2)$, where $E_1$ and $E_2$ and are pieces of evidence in favor of some hypothesis $H$. I want to use the law of total probability to decompose it:

$[P(E_1|H)P(H)+P(E_1|\neg H)P(\neg H)]\cdot [P(E_2|H)P(H)+P(E_2|\neg H)P(\neg H)]$

I'm trying to interpret this equation, and am having trouble making sense of the cross-products, e.g., $P(E_1|\neg H)P(\neg H)\cdot P(E_2|H)P(H)$. I have the feeling that these terms should drop out, since $H$ and $\neg H$ cannot simultaneously obtain. However, there is no algebraic reason why I could ignore these terms.